# If $a<b$, $c<d$, $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$, what does $[c,d]\subseteq f([a,b])$ imply?

Tags: functions

So if you have some real numbers $a,b,c,d$ with $a<b$ and $c<d$, and you also have a function $f$ on the real numbers with $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$, what does it imply if you show that for any $y\in[c,d]$ there is some $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=y$?

It doesn't prove $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ right? You would need $f$ to be linear for that to be true I think.

Does $f(a)=c$, $f(b)=d$ and $f$ is linear imply that $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ is a bijection?

Comment: $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ means that *every* member of $[a,b]$ gets mapped to a member of $[c,d].$ Your first paragraph does not imply that this is necessarily the case. Also, I think the answer to your last question is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

> What does it imply if you show that for any $y\in[c,d]$ there is some $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=y$?

It is equivalent to the statement that there exists some subset $X$ of $[a,b]$ such that the restriction $f:X\to [c,d]$ is a well-defined surjection.

> Does $f(a)=c$, $f(b)=d$ and $f$ is linear imply that $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ is a bijection?

Yes. Here is an inefficient but IMO conceptually illuminating proof sketch:

1. First, explain why there is only one linear function with $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$.
2. Then for any reals $x<y$, let $g_{x,y}: [0,1]\to[x,y]$ such that $g_{x,y}(t) = tx + (1-t)y$. Notice this is linear in $t$, and prove it has an inverse. (Hint: Geometrically, why must $g_{x,y}^{-1}$ send $\frac{x+y}{2}\mapsto \frac{1}{2}$?)
3. Finally, consider $f^*=g_{c,d}\circ g_{a,b}^{-1}$. This is a composition of two bijections, thus a bijection $[a,b]\to[c,d]$. But also it is the composition of two linear functions, thus linear, and so $f^*=f$ by Part 1.

> It doesn't prove $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ right? You would need $f$ to be linear for that to be true I think.

As Adam Robinson points out in the comments, no. The issue is (in my notation) that $X$ need not be all of $[a,b]$. Linear is sufficient under the additional constraints $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$; hopefully it's clear why those constraints are needed. However, we certainly would not "need" $f$ to be linear! For instance $f(x)=1/x$ gives a perfectly good nonlinear bijection from $[\frac13,\frac12]\to [2,3]$.